# Finding tangent of an angle, which is between two lines

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

In the paper I have two lines which have an angle between them (letter C). Also it is told that **area** of one square is $1 cm^2$. I need to find tangent of the angle C.

What I know is square's side length is 1cm. I tried finding the length of line CB(pythagorean theorem) and drawing the line $AB$.

I know the answer which is $-2.5$

[image: image of the paper]

Comment: You could use the fact that $\tan(180^{\rm o}-\angle {\rm C})=-\tan(\angle{\rm C})$

Comment: Could you explain it a bit wider? By the way, the answer is -2.5. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I had been out for a little while, but ATHARVA has perfectly answered your question.

Comment: Count squares and divide.

Answer (score 3):

produce AC to D. and join  BD such that angle CDB forms right angle.

NOW $\tan CDB = \frac{5}{2}$
           $ = 2.5$

now $$\tan C = \tan 180-CDB$$
   $$ \tan C =-\tan CDB$$
   $$ \tan C = -2.5$$